# GPO says Version Mismatch on Domain Controller when Versions appear to Match

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, replication

On my primary domain controller, the AD and Syslog version of each of my GPO policies appears to match correctly:
[image]

However, when I run a Group Policy Results report, it says that their is an "AD / SYSLOG Version Mismatch":
[image]

According to repadmin /showrepl, my replication is up and working correctly:
[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: Could be not related, but there's a hotfix for this, check if applies to your case: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2866345/-ad-sysvol-version-mismatch-message-is-displayed-unexpectedly-in-the-group-policy-results-report-in-windows